# Node.js Express server: running res.render() / ejs.render() using Node.js threadpool

Tags: node.js, express, server-side, ejs

We have an app that uses server-side rendering for SEO purposes using EJS templating.

I am well-versed with Node.js and know that it's probably possible to tap into the Node.js threadpool for asynchronous I/O for whatever purpose you want, whether it's a good idea or a bad idea. Currently I am wondering if it is possible to run ejs.render() or res.render() with a thread in the threadpool instead of the main thread in Node.js?

We are doing a lot of heavy computational lifting in the render functions and we definitely want that off the main thread, otherwise we will be paying $$$ for more servers.

Comment: we *could* use a separate Node.js process to run rendering on, or even a webworker-thread (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) but I am specifically wondering if there is a way to tap into the existing threadpool in V8

Answer (score 1):

Is it just the rendering that is concerning you? There are other template engines which should produce better results; being that template rendering should be an idempotent operation, you could additionally distribute across a cluster.

V8 will compile your code to assembly and, if your not hitting any deoptimizations or getting stalled by the garbage collector, I believe you should be in the neighborhood of your network I/O limits. I would definitely recommend you try other template engines, adding a caching HTTP reverse proxy at the front and running some benchmarks first.

Comment: well unfortunately at this stage theres no way we will rewrite using a different template library, but yeah it's the rendering that concerns me, it's a lot of cpu

Comment: @AlexMills I would still try to add a caching reverse proxy and run some benchmarks, i.e. opening all documents from `robots.txt`, concurrently and at random and measuring the load. The only next thing you can incline towards is finding a native template engine--I don't know how much will this boost performances, since string operations are measured at the order of millions per second; it would also force you to rewrite the template code since EJS can contain evaluations for any JS code, while the template engine implemented in something other than Node.js certainly will not.

Answer (score 1):

EJS is known to be synchronous, and that's not going to change, so basically it's an inefficient rendering engine for Node.js since it blocks the JS thread whenever it renders a view, which degrades your overall throughput, especially if your rendering is CPU heavy.

You should definitely think about some other options. E.g. https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars

If you really have CPU-heavy computation in your webserver, then Node.js is definitely not the right tool for the job anyway. There are much better servers to handle multi-threading and parallel processing. You could just setup Node to be a controller and forward your CPU-heavy requests to a backend service/server that can do the heavy-lifting.

It would be helpful to see what kind of computation you are doing during render to provide a better answer.

Tapping into the thread-pool (which is handled by `libuv`) would probably be a bad idea, but it is possible of course.. you just need some C++ skills and the `uv_queue_work()` method of the `libuv` library to schedule stuff on a worker thread.

Comment: what asynchronous templating engines do you know of for node.js?

Comment: it won't be that hard to use a separate node.js process to do the rendering, but I guess this question originally was trying to find information about how to access the node.js threadpool from inside the main thread, if that's possible. Right? Because these async templating libraries you reference must be doing that, unless they are just using streams somehow and not doing work off the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented with building a scripting engine that is run in a forked process (Read on node's child process module [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)). I find that to be an attractive proposition for implementing rendering engines. Yes there are issues of passing parameters (post/get query strings, session status, etc) but they are easy to deal with, especially if you use the fork option (as opposed to exec or spawn). There are standard messaging methods to communicate between the child and parent.

The only overhead is the generation of the additional instance of node (the rendering engine itself). If you are doing extensive computation in the scripting engine then this constant, the one-time per rendering request overhead of forking a new process will be minor compared to the time taken to render.

If EJS rendering blocks the main node thread, then that alone is sufficient reason NOT to use it if you are doing any significant computation during rendering.